# Access to project

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, nuxt.js

I've got Windows 7 on my pc and Ubuntu as a virtual machine.
VM stack is VirtualBox + Vagrant + Homestead box.

I'm starting hot-reload Nuxt.js server on vm at http://localhost:3000.

How can i access it via browser on my host machine?

Answer (score 0):

Run `vagrant ssh`.

Then `ifconfig` & look for ip address starting with `192.168`

Just use it to access it on your windows machine browser. Dont forget to add port to ip address.

Comment: I've done ifconfig, 192.168.10.10 is result, but if i try to access http://192.168.10.10:3000 browser says page not found. My 
Ifconfig:
enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:e3:02:f3  
          inet addr:192.168.10.10  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fee3:2f3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

Answer (score 0):

Do you have port 3000 open and forwarding correctly on the VM? Try running `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` on the VM and see what the output is when you try connecting to `192.168.10.10:3000`. Can you connect to port 80?